# Update Document by ID field using Mongo DB C# Driver

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I am using the latest MongoDB C# Driver and I am having a problem with one of my queries. I am trying to update a field in a document in Mongo and identify this document by it's id field. I have written similar queries that filter  the documents based on other field but for some wreason it doesn't work with the id field.

My Query:

```
public static async Task<bool> Delete(string Guid)
{
var database = new MongoDB();
var thingsCollection = database.Things;
var builder = Builders<ThingsModel>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq("_id", Guid);
var update = Builders<ThingsModel>.Update
    .Set("IsActive", false);
var updateResult = await thingsCollection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
return true;         
}
```

I realise I am returning true each time but that is just there for testing. The updateResult object that comes back from Mongo says it didn't find any matches despite the being a thing in the thingsCollection with the Guid passed in the as a parameter. I have also marked the Guid property to be the ID Field in the collection as follows:

```
[BsonId]
public Guid Guid { get; set; }
```

Also I know I need to change the name from Guid to something else as it bad practice but one thing at a time :) I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5):

there could be an issue with your naming.

Using linqu syntax we can have this (_id is used as id field ):

```
var update = Builders<ThingsModel>.Update.Set(a => a.IsActive, false); 
var result = _collection.UpdateOne(model => model._id == _id, update);
```

[full code here](https://github.com/profesor79/SOSolver/blob/master/SoQuestionsSolver/SoQuestionsSolver/UpdateDocumentByIdFieldSteps.cs)